# sony sbh-50 and sony smart watch 2 connection

Tags: sony-smartwatch

I currently have an SBH-50 paired with my Snote2 running on 4.4.2 Kitkat. My question is, if i get a smart watch 2, will the watch and sbh-50 work at the same time to control my samsung note 2? thanks a lot :)

Comment: still no response :(